# if condition based on smarty day of the week and hour of the 24H day in prestashop TPL

Tags: task-parallel-library, prestashop, smarty, date-format, strtotime

Good Afternoon,
I'm trying to code an in-page informative in my prestashop template where the product page of each item, based on availability, provides information regarding possible delivery day.
The instrument should show specific rules based on our of the day (24H) and day of the week (1 per Monday, 2 per Tuesday...).
As per now, thanks to an original comment on prestashop forum itself, I have managed to have a working only-on-day-of-the-week based code that actually works, as follows:

```
{if $product->quantity >= 1}            
  {assign var="Delivery_day" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%u"}
  {l s='If you are ordering before 11:30 a.m.,  delivery to Italy will be between'}
    {if $Delivery_day == 7}
        {"+2 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} {l s='and'} {"+3 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"}
    {/if}
    {if $Delivery_day == 6}
        {"+3 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} {l s='and'} {"+4 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"}
    {/if}    
    {if $Delivery_day > 0 && $Delivery_day < 6}
        {"tomorrow"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} {l s='and'} {"+2 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"}
    {/if}
    {l s='. If later, please get in touch so we can inform you if still able to ship today. For deliveries outside Italy, please count 72H for EU and up to 1 Week for Extra EU'}
{/if}
```

The update I have coded is the following:

```
{if $product->quantity >= 1}        
  {assign var="Delivery_day" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%u"}
  {assign var="Delivery_hour" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%k"}
 {l s='Order now and receive you order in'}
    <!-- Domenica -->
    {if $Delivery_day == 7} 
    {"+2 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} {l s='and'} {"+3 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"}
    {/if}
    <!-- Sabato-->
    {if $Delivery_day == 6}
        {"+3 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} {l s='and'} {"+4 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} 
        {/if}
    <!-- Prima di Mezzo Giorno-->
    {if $Delivery_hour > 0 && $Delivery_hour < 12 && $Delivery_hour = 0}
        <!-- Lun-Giov-->
    {if $Delivery_day > 0 && $Delivery_day < 5}
        {"tomorrow"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} {l s='and'} {"+2 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"}
    {/if}
        <!-- Venerdì-->
    {if $Delivery_day == 5}
        {"+3 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} {l s='and'} {"+4 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"}
    {/if}
    {/if}
   <!-- Dopo di Mezzo Giorno-->
    {if $Delivery_hour >= 12 && $Delivery_hour <= 23 }
        <!-- Lun-Giov-->
    {if $Delivery_day > 0 && $Delivery_day < 5}
        {"+2 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} {l s='and'} {"+3 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"}
    {/if}
        <!-- Venerdì-->
    {if $Delivery_day == 5}
        {"+4 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"} {l s='and'} {"+5 days"|strtotime|date_format:"d-m-Y"}
    {/if}
    {/if}
    {l s='. If later, please get in touch so we can inform you if still able to ship today. For deliveries outside Italy, please count 72H for EU and up to 1 Week for Extra EU'}
{/if}
```

But, unfortunately, my attempt was unsuccessful and I was wondering if there was any chance to understand which conflict I may have created.
Thanks for any reply.
Have a good day!
Francesco

Comment: I think you have made a very confused code with a lot of `if` and some of them never will enter in the condition, like this `{if $Delivery_hour > 0 && $Delivery_hour < 12 && $Delivery_hour = 0}`. If you want a recommendation, you should try to achieve this in a php file and then send the final content to Smarty, also you should try to use a `switch` instead of `if`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. Now I understood that the logical of && should not be used in more than 2 variables. Thanks to that, I did corrected as follows:
(It says too long), but I just cancelled && $Delivery_hour = 0} getting the following result: {if $Delivery_hour >= 0 && $Delivery_hour < 12} and now it works just fine!
Thanks again.